# Duplicate site or a part of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Today while I was searching for an answer to a question I noticed a site, [dingding.in](http://dingding.in). Is it a part of Stack Exchange or what?

http://magento.dingding.in/q/16336?lq=1